# Using jQuery to publish news

Tags: jquery, html, forms, append

I'm trying to get more familiar with jQuery and are going to make myself an admin panel where i can publish newes and ongoing projects to my front page.

So my question is how can i do this?

I have a news div in Index.php called: `<div class="latest_news"></div>`

Then i make this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=publishNews]').val();   
        $(".latest_news").append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>')
    });  
});
```

This is the jQuery that is gonna publish the news.

And my form is:

```
<form name="publishNewsForm">
        <input type="text" name="publishNews">
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
    </form>
```

This works if i put up a div on the publish_news.php page where the form is and call it `.latest_news`
But not when i try to publish it on the index.php file.

Anyone more familiar with jQuery that can point me in the right direction on how i can get this one working to publish from a form in page: publish_news.php to a div in index.php.

Thanks.

Comment: So in what file your form is - `index.php` or `publish_news.php`?

Comment: My form is in publish_news.php and the DIV that is gonna show the news is in index.php

Comment: As `http` is a stateless protocol and javascript is a client-side language, you can't do what you want this way. Either `POST` from publish to index, or use some storage - database, files, whatever.

Comment: Hmm. Okey. Thanks. I will see what i can find out. 

So i guess that PHP is the best alternative with a database here?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library and JavaScript doesn't deal with databases, unless you use node.js for the back end. You can use jQuery to manipulate DOM elements after the page is produced by PHP or node.js or java or just plain HTML, but you need some server-side programming language to query the database.